# How to get command prompt # in switch hp procurve 2910

Tags: hp-procurve

I´m using 'enable'from the command prompt > to get access to the command prompt #. Doing this I get a list of commands starting with the word 'enable' but the command prompt doesn´t change. What could be the solution?. 
It has been a long time since the last time I had to work with switches...
Thank you for your help

Comment: What model of switch are you working with?

Comment: Just to be clear: do you get enable rights when you type `enable`? So is your problem that your prompt does not change, or that the `enable` command does not work?

Comment: The model of switch is HP ProCurve 2910al-24G (J9145A). I´ve used the command 'help' before and after using 'enable' and I get the same list of commands, so I suppose that it has no effect... I´ve added a comment below with the output of the command 'enable'

Comment: I tried the same thing on a 2910al-24G, and I get output consistent with my answer below. I also tried logging in as a restricted operator user, and I get the same non-privileged prompt. What firmware are you running? Can you type just "help" and copy the list of commands here (I'm trying to figure out what context that you might be in)?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your problem exactly is, but here's how it works on a HP Procurve switch

```
Switch1> enable
Username: root
Password: password
Your previous successful login (as manager) was on 1990-02-28 02:54:09
 from 192.168.0.1
Switch1#
```

Then to access the configuration options, you need to type **conf**

```
Switch1# conf
Switch1(config)#
```

Comment: CEGET_SW1_8GB:root> enable
enable .
enable :
enable [
enable alias
enable bg
enable bind
...
enable wait
CEGET_SW1_8GB:root>

Comment: This is the output I get when I use ‘enable’:
CEGET_SW1_8GB:root> enable
enable .
enable :
enable [
enable alias
enable bg
enable bind
...
enable wait
CEGET_SW1_8GB:root>
So finally I don´t get the command prompt #

Comment: CEGET_SW1_8GB:root>
CEGET_SW1_8GB:root> enable exec
CEGET_SW1_8GB:root>
This is what I get when I use 'enable exec'. The output is the same with any other command 'enable...'